# error: too many padding sections on right border

Tags: android, android-drawable, nine-patch, xml-drawable, aapt2

when i build my project it give me error like

[image: getting this error]

I found the reason that, because of 9 patch file i am getting this error. so can any one please look at this 9-patch file for whats wrong in this below image.

[image: drop_down_9_patch image]

also i am using layer list for this drop down which is below

drop_down_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/black_c4c4c4" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="@dimen/margin_8"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_down_arrow_9"
        android:left="@dimen/margin_8"
        android:right="@dimen/margin_8"
        android:top="@dimen/margin_8">
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and this above drawable i am using in `Spinner` background.

please give solution for that 9 patch file

Comment: you cannot use two or more lines on bottom and right side, more: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawables#nine-patch

Comment: okay thank you let me try that as your said. @pskink

Comment: honestly i dont think you need "paddig box" at all... so make bottom ent right side empty

Comment: okay thank you. @pskink its worked fine as you said for remove right side two line.