# Android gradle build error: too many padding sections on bottom border

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

i'm migrating an old android project from Eclipse to Android Studio, after resolving java errors i'm facing this error that i couldn't find where is exactly located.

here is the error output:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':marghrebail_v3:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
  error: too many padding sections on bottom border.
```

Comment: Post your app level as well project level gradle

Comment: It appears issue with your drawable resource. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50112281/error-too-many-padding-sections-on-right-border